# Recyclerview doesn't actually Recycle Views?

Tags: android

I read that RecyclerView should never have layout_height="wrap_content" because it won't recycle the views.

I tested this by creating that with 100 items.

I scrolled to the bottom and used layoutInspector. It showed only a couple items under the RecyclerView, not 100.  I also tested with a recycerview layout_height=200dp and saw the same result.

It seems the views are still being recycled. Am I misinterpreting what he's saying or are layout_height=wrap_content and layout_height=fixedDp irrelevant to recycling?

Comment: Please paste whatever code you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android:layout_height` values of `wrap_content` or a fixed height are irrelevant to recycling.

However, `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` is not a good idea in general for vertically-scrolling widgets, such as a `RecyclerView` with a vertical `LinearLayoutManager`. Since the content varies, the size may be unpredictable. Use something else to control the height to be what you want regardless of the content, such as constraining its top and bottom within a `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: could you further explain why an uknown size ia a problem?  If the recyclerview layout_height is "wrap_content" it looks the same as one with "match_parent".  I do see a difference if this is applied to the individual item.

Comment: @Marc: " If the recyclerview layout_height is "wrap_content" it looks the same as one with "match_parent"" -- I simply would not count on that behavior being universal.

Comment: I'm not able to picture this.  I also think of different possible item views.  If the adapter contents is less than the current window wouldnt they look the same?  Same for extending beyond that window.

Comment: @Marc: Many layouts put other widgets above or below the vertically-scrollable widget. Depending on your choice of container (e.g., `LinearLayout`), the size of the vertically-scrollable widget can affect those adjacent widgets. The safest thing to do is to ensure that the height of the vertically-scrollable widget is controlled, so you control the placement of those adjacent widgets.

Comment: I think wrap_content is ok now, but sadly there is no clear solution in case it gets more complicated, such as RecyclerView within NestedScrollView (in the same orientation)